# Error updating mysql table's column

Tags: mysql

I messed up one of the columns of my database while url encoding the input. Now all the spaces are replced by a "+" sign.

I tried updating the DB using the following query but it throws me error

```
UPDATE tableName SET 'columnName' = REPLACE('columnName','+',' ')";
```

Error i am getting is :

Unknown column 'columnName' in 'field list'

Comment: UPDATE tableName SET `columnName` = REPLACE(`columnName`,'+',' ')";

Comment: remove the quotations for the columnName!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use quote mark for column name, Try this**

```
 UPDATE tableName SET columnName = REPLACE(columnName,'+',' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Remove single quote wrapped around the column name

```
UPDATE tableName SET `columnName` = REPLACE(`columnName`,'+',' ')";
```